# I have a Children form called Products, which is active on MDIForm called Form1

Tags: c

How can I display the Add Product form instead of the Products form by clicking on button 1 on the Products form.

This is how I displayed the Child Form:
(Code FORM1)

```
public void activeChildrenForms(Form form)
        {
            disposeChildrenForms(form);
            form.MdiParent = this;
            form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Show();
        }
```

And thus i destroy a form already created:

```
public void disposeChildrenForms(Form form)
        {
            foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                if(!frm.Focused)
                {
                    frm.Visible = false;
                    frm.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried such a variant but it doesn't show me anything:
In Product Form I added;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.activeChildrenForms(new AddProduct());
        }
```

Comment: @TomKarzes, this doesn't look C++ too. Looks like C#.

Comment: @kiner_shah Ok, I'll take your word for it.  It's definitely not C.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes it looks like i messed up, it's c #